# ASP.NET Gridview SelectedRowStyle and EditRowStyle

Tags: asp.net, gridview, styles

I want the gridview SelectedRowStyle and EditRowStyles to be mutually exclusive so that the edit-row style is turned off when another row is selected and the selected-row style is turned off when another row is put in editing mode. I tried handling OnRowEditing and changing the CssClass for the currently selected row, but that didn't work.

Thanks!

Comment: Found a solution. Here are the event handlers: 
protected void Grid1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) { 
    Grid1.SelectedRowStyle.CssClass = "selected";
    Grid1.EditRowStyle.CssClass = ""; } 

protected void Grid1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e) { 
    Grid1.SelectedIndex = e.NewEditIndex; //not needed for style but switching selected index to be consistent
    Grid1.SelectedRowStyle.CssClass = "";
    Grid1.EditRowStyle.CssClass = "selected"; }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you saying you want selection and editing to be mutually exclusive? If so, this should work if you're using the usual command buttons (autogenerate edit, autogenerate select).

```
    protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Select")
    {
        GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
    }
    else if (e.CommandName == "Edit")
    {
        GridView1.SelectedIndex = -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Good solution! I just hit on this myself after making my last comment, but props to you.